# PGSQL2SHP Commnad switch column type

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, import, pgsql2shp

I work with Postgis. I have table

```
CREATE TABLE centerline
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  l_from integer,
  l_to integer,
  r_add_pre character varying(15),
  r_to integer ... 
}
```

Export this table with PGSQL2SHP command

command is

```
pgsql2shp  -f centerline.shp -h localhost -u redsky ....
```

and when I imported it  back with command

```
shp2pgsql -i  -s 4326 centerline.shp
```

it generates table

```
 CREATE TABLE centerline
    (
      gid serial NOT NULL,
      l_from double precision,
      l_to double precision,
      r_add_pre character varying(15),
      r_to double precision ... 
    }
```

I do not want double type.  Can Anybody help me?

Comment: The DBF format that is used in shapefiles does not have a real integer/double support. Could you send the output from ogrinfo from the centerline.shp? The command to use is `ogrinfo -al -so centerline.shp`

Comment: l_from: Real (11.0)
l_to: Real (11.0)
this is output then export. why Real? i have integer in DB

Comment: Because DBF format does not have integers. Your column is a "general number with 11 digits, zero decimals" which is correct. Number without decimals is an integer. Shp2pgsql should do the conversion right. There must be something that I do not understand. Can you try to save the centerline.shp into PostGIS with ogr2ogr and compare the result?

Comment: I have other shape files output is 
r_from: Integer (9.0)
r_to: Integer (9.0), but where I import and then export output is Real...

Comment: Ok, the reason is perhaps here http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.gdal.devel/37675
An integer with 11 numbers can be bigger than what can be expressed as 32 bit signed integer and PostgreSQL like GDAL wants to avoid possible overflow by converting it into double. I do not know how to make pgsql2shp to output something like "number 9.0" which should solve your problem.

Comment: I have integer type  which is (32 bit integer). i can not understand why convert to real type

Comment: But if I have smaillInt , field type in exported file is Integer

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand this. I am mainly repeating what I have been told when I have had similar problems. By reading http://dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm I guess I were wrong when I wrote that dbf III does not have integers. There seems to be a type "long". However, I do not know if shapefiles are using it. If you want to get a really good answer try to reach some pgsql2shp developer and ask why the utility behaves like it does.